# Question on Lp Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Exercise:

Assume $E$ has finite measure and $1\le p_{1}<p_{2}\le\infty$.  Show that if {$f_{n}$}$\space\rightarrow f$ in $L^{p_{2}}(E)$ then {$f_{n}$}$\space\rightarrow f$ in $L^{p_{1}}(E)$

Proof:

Take $p_{1}<p_{2}$ then $||f||_{p_{1}}\le||f||_{p_{2}}$

$0 \le||f_n-f||_{p_{1}}\le||f_n-f||_{p_{2}} \rightarrow 0$

$\therefore ${$f_{n}$}$\space\rightarrow f$ in $L^{p_{1}}(E)$

Is this correct?

Comment: It's not quite correct, since you don't necessarily have $\lVert f\rVert_{p_1}\leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{p_2}$. You have a factor depending on $p_1,p_2$ and $\mu(E)$. $$\lVert 1\rVert_p = \mu(E)^{1/p},$$ and for $\mu(E) > 1$, that is decreasing in $p$.

Comment: If I were to modify it to say that $||f_n-f|| \le m(E)^{(p_2-p_1)/(p_1p_2)} ||f_n-f|| \rightarrow 0$ then thats the general idea?  The case above would be correct if the $m(E)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Daniel Fischer, the inequality $\lVert f\rVert_{p_1}\leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{p_2}$ doest not necessarily hold.

However, notice that for a fixed $\varepsilon$ 
\begin{align*}\int_E |f_n-f|^{p_1}dx&=\int_{\{|f_n-f|<\varepsilon\}}|f_n-f|^{p_1}dx+
\int_{\{|f_n-f|\geqslant \varepsilon\}}|f_n-f|^{p_1}dx\\
&\leqslant \varepsilon^{p_1}\mu(E)+\varepsilon^{p_1}\int_{\{|f_n-f|\geqslant \varepsilon\}}\left(\frac{|f_n-f|}{\varepsilon}\right)^{p_1}dx\\
&\leqslant  \varepsilon^{p_1}\mu(E)+\varepsilon^{p_1}\int_{\{|f_n-f|\geqslant \varepsilon\}}\left(\frac{|f_n-f|}{\varepsilon}\right)^{p_2}dx\\
&\leqslant  \varepsilon^{p_1}\mu(E)+\varepsilon^{p_1-p_2}\int |f_n-f|^{p_2}dx.
\end{align*}
We infer that 
$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\int_E |f_n-f|^{p_1}dx\leqslant \varepsilon^{p_1}\mu(E),$$
and we conclude, as $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary.